# Statmodel OLS fails at column names with multiple words-Linear regression

Tags: pandas, regression, linear-regression, transformation, least-squares

I trying a simple linear regression using ols and it fails at columns with multiple word name.

```
mod = smf.ols(formula='Sales ~ Sub Region + Customer Segment', data=df)
```

I am searching how to fix but none has worked so far. The Q transformation I found [here](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html)as I use it below dsnt resolve it either. Does anyone know how can get this fixed?

```
mod = smf.ols(formula='Sales ~ Q(Sub Region) + Q(Customer Segment)', data=df)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149482/using-ols-function-with-parameters-that-contain-numbers-spaces should solve your problem

Comment: Q transformation works. I only needed a double quote. This worked:mod = smf.ols(formula='Sales ~ Q("Sub Region") + Q("Customer Segment")', data=df)